# Laravel customize create() method on model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to extend the `create()` method on a model so that every time you call a `create()` it does some stuff before insert the row.

For example I have a `Balance` model, which has fields `amount` and `ending_balance`.  I want to be able to only specify the `amount` when `create()` and then have the `ending_balance` automatically calculated within the model (ie by looking up the previous `ending_balance`)

I'd also like to be able to put all the create logic within a `DB::transaction()` so that I can lock the rows while doing the calculations.

I've added this to my model, but it never hits the dd() when creating.

```
class Balance extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public static function create(array $attributes = [])
    {
        dd($attributes);
        // Calculate the ending_balance here 

        return parent::create($attributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use Model events.

This link describes how to do it using closures:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

the "created/creating" event might be what you are looking for. If things need to be recalculated, take a look at the updating/updated events.

```
 class Balance extends Model
    {
        protected static function booted()
        {
            static::created(function ($user) {
                // Calculate the fields value here
            });
        }
    }
```

I personally think overriding the create method is a little bit odd, and I've never seen anyone doing it. It might be not obvious for your teammates too. Just stick with events.

Another question was - how to do things in a transaction. Answer: use Laravel DB facade to run code in a transaction:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    Balance::create([...]);
    OtherMode::create([...]);
});
```

This will commit the transaction after the last line in the closure.

You can also manually control transactions:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
DB::rollBack();
DB::commit();
```

Comment: `creating` event would probably be more appropriate but events looks like a good idea here

Comment: Thank you, I have now been able to do this using the `creating` event; however how would I put the whole create queries into a DB transaction?

Comment: @DavidB see an updated answer on how to deal with transactions